# Object modification modal window on the click of a button Spring MVC and JSP?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I am developing an intranet portal with spring mvc and jsp.
The problem: in a jsp page, I list objects. At the click of a button, I would like to open a modal window (bootstrap) with a modification form of this object with its old information. But I can not understand the logic / technique
to implement to achieve this. I spent a lot of time searching in the internet, but I didn't find any useful solution. Could someone give me an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: thanks for your answer could you please check my jsp page code as well as controller updateTeam method. with this code, on the button clic, modification modal window appears with old values but when i click edit button in the modal to confirm modification nothing occurs.

Comment: The last version i posted is formatted and updated. Could you check it as well as the controller in the image

Answer (score 0):

If I were at this situation (have been), I would do something like this:

**1-** First create a `bootstrap` modal with the values that are already there and which you want to edit. Let's say we have three things that you want to edit namely firstname, middlename and lastname. So create a modal with three `inputs` which shall show these values in a text box and create similar number of input fields but hidden. So in total 6 (3 visible - 3 hidden - all with different `id`'s of course.)

**2-** Now when you click on let's say that `Edit` button, `show` this `modal` with the values set to the values that are present (can use `jQuery` to set the values of input). So hidden fname input and visible fname input should be set to the First Name that should be edited. Similarly for middlename and lastname.

**3-** Now you can modify the values in your modal. So now the values of your shown inputs will change while the hidden inputs will still carry the older values.

**4-** Do `getParameter` of all these 6 values in your `Servlet` and use the hidden values to update them to new values. Always make sure that you provide a value that shall not change (sort of primary key) that will help you with the identification and updation.

Hope that paints a picture. Let me know if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
 prefix="security"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec"
 uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- Mirrored from iamsrinu.com/bluemoon2.1/calendar.html by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2014], Tue, 01 Aug 2017 10:53:49 GMT -->

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="resources/template/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
 media="screen">
<link href="resources/template/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="resources/template/css/color-picker/minicolors.css"
 rel="stylesheet">
<link href="resources/template/fonts/icomoon/icomoon.css"
 rel="stylesheet">
<link href="resources/template/css/wysiwyg-editor/editor.css"
 rel="stylesheet">
<link href="resources/template/css/datatables/fixedHeader.bs.css"
 rel="stylesheet">
<link href="resources/template/css/datatables/dataTables.bs.min.css"
 rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="resources/template/css/datatables/autoFill.bs.min.css">
<%@include file="static/header.jsp"%>
</head>

<body>
 <%@include file="static/top-header.jsp"%>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
  <%@include file="static/nav.jsp"%>
  <div class="dashboard-wrapper">
   <div class="top-bar clearfix">
    <div class="row gutter">
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="page-title">
       <h4>Gestion des Equipes</h4>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="main-container">
    <div class="row gutter">
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="panel panel-blue">

       <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4>Liste des Equipes</h4>
       </div>

       <div id="menuBarDiv" style="margin-left: 500px;">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">
         <i class="icon-printer2"></i> Imprimer
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="openAddModalBtn">
         <i class="icon-users3"></i> Nouvelle Equipe
        </button>
       </div>

       <div class="bar bar-header"></div>
       <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="table-responsive">
         <table id="tableTeams"
          class="table table-striped table-bordered no-margin">
          <thead>
           <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Nom</th>
            <th class="text-center">Validateur</th>
            <th class="text-center">Couleur</th>
            <th class="text-center">Statut</th>
            <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
           </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
           <c:forEach var="t" items="${teams}">
            <tr>
             <td class="text-center">${t.name }</td>
             <td class="text-center">${t.validateur.firstName}
              ${t.validateur.lastName}</td>
             <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-square"
              aria-hidden="true"
              style="background-color:<c:out value="${t.color}"></c:out>; width= "></i></td>
             <td class="text-center"><c:choose>
               <c:when test="${t.isActif == true }">
                <i class="icon-lens" style="color: #077a07;"></i>
               </c:when>
               <c:when test="${t.isActif == false }">
                <i class="icon-lens" style="color: #c20b0b;"></i>
               </c:when>
              </c:choose></td>
             <td class="text-center"><a
              href="#update-team-modal_${t.id}" role="button"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-transparent btn-info"
              data-toggle="modal"><i
               class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-placement="bottom"
               title="Editer"></i></a> <a
              href="detailsTeam?id=<c:out value="${t.id}"></c:out>">
               <button class="btn btn-xs btn-transparent btn-info">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"
                 data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
                 title="Voir Détails"></i>
               </button>
             </a><a
              href="desactivateTeam?id=<c:out value="${t.id}"></c:out>">
               <button class="btn btn-xs btn-transparent btn-danger ">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-off"
                 data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
                 title="Désactiver"></i>
               </button>
             </a></td>
            </tr>
            <div class="modal fade" id="update-team-modal_${t.id}"
             tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
             aria-hidden="true">
             <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                <h5>Modification Equipe</h5>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="updateTeamForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                 method="POST" action="updateTeam">

                 <div class="form-group">
                  <input id="id" type="hidden" name="id"
                   class="form-control" value="${t.id}">
                 </div>
                 
                 <label for="name">Nom </label><span class="req">*
                 </span>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group">
                   <input type="text" name="name" id="name"
                    class="form-control-large" value="${t.name }"
                    required="required" />
                  </div>
                 </div>
                 
                 <label for="color">Couleur</label><span class="req">*
                 </span>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" id="color" name="color"
                   class="form-control demo" style="width: 200px;"
                   data-swatches="#fff|#000|#f00|#0f0|#00f|#ff0|#0ff"
                   value="${t.color}" required="required">
                 </div>
                 
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="validateur">Validateur</label> <span
                   class="req">* </span> <select
                   class="form-control-small" id="validateur"
                   name="validateur" required="required">
                   <option value="${t.validateur.matricule}">${t.validateur.firstName }
                    ${t.validateur.lastName }</option>
                   <c:forEach var="u" items="${users}">
                    <option value="${u.matricule}">${u.firstName}
                     ${u.lastName}</option>
                   </c:forEach>
                  </select>
                 </div>
                </form>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                <a><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-ok" data-dismiss="modal">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" id="update"></i>Editer
                 </button></a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                 data-dismiss="modal">
                 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>Annuler
                </button>
               </div>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </c:forEach>
          </tbody>
         </table>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="modal fade" id="add-team-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <h5>Nouvelle Equipe</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <form id="addTeamForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"
      action="addTeam">
      <label for="name">Nom </label><span class="req">* </span>
      <div class="form-group">
       <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"
         class="form-control-large" required="required" />
       </div>
      </div>
      <label for="color">Couleur</label><span class="req">* </span>
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" id="color" name="color"
        class="form-control demo" style="width: 200px;"
        data-swatches="#fff|#000|#f00|#0f0|#00f|#ff0|#0ff"
        required="required">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="validateur">Validateur</label> <span class="req">*
       </span> <select class="form-control-small" id="validateur"
        name="validateur" required="required">
        <option value="">-- Sélectionner un validateur --</option>
        <c:forEach var="u" items="${users}">
         <option value="${u.matricule}">${u.firstName}
          ${u.lastName}</option>
        </c:forEach>
       </select>
      </div>
     </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <a><button type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-info btn-ok">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>Créer
      </button></a>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="cancelAdd"
      data-dismiss="modal">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>Annuler
     </button>
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>



 <%@include file="static/footer.jsp"%>
 <script src="resources/template/js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/template/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/template/js/scrollup/jquery.scrollUp.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/template/js/sparkline/sparkline.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/template/js/sparkline/custom-sparkline.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/template/js/databars/jquery.databar.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/template/js/databars/custom-databars.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/template/js/datatables/dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <script
  src="resources/template/js/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/template/js/datatables/autoFill.min.js"></script>
 <script
  src="resources/template/js/datatables/autoFill.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/template/js/datatables/fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/template/js/datatables/custom-datatables.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/template/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/template/js/custom.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/template/js/fileinput/fr.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/template/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/template/js/color_picker/jscolor.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/template/js/color-picker/minicolors.min.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/template/js/color-picker/custom-colorpicker.js"></script>

 <script>
  $("#filtre").on("change", function() {
   var selected = this.value;
  });

  $('#openAddModalBtn').on('click', function() {
   $('#add-team-modal').modal('toggle');

  });

  $('#cancelAdd').on('click', function() {
   $('#add-team-modal').find("input").val('').end();
   document.getElementById('validateur').selectedIndex = 0;
  });

  $('#save').on('click', function() {

   $('#addTeamForm').ajaxForm({
    success : function(data) {
     var res = JSON.parse(data);
     if (res.code == 1) {
      $('#add-team-modal').modal('hide');
      location.reload();
      $('#add-team-modal').find("input").val('').end();
     }

     else {
      toastr["error"](res.message);
     }
    },
    error : function(error) {
     console.log(error);
    }
   }).submit();
  });

  $('#update').on('click', function() {

   $('#updateTeamForm').ajaxForm({
    success : function(data) {
     var res = JSON.parse(data);
     if (res.code == 1) {
      $('#add-team-modal').modal('hide');
      location.reload();
     }

     else {
      toastr["error"](res.message);
     }
    },
    error : function(error) {
     console.log(error);
    }
   }).submit();
  });
  $('#tableTeams').DataTable({
   "language" : {
    "url" : "resources/template/lang/French.json"
   }
  });
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F96HL.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
    prefix="security"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec"
    uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- Mirrored from iamsrinu.com/bluemoon2.1/calendar.html by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2014], Tue, 01 Aug 2017 10:53:49 GMT -->

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="resources/template/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    media="screen">
<link href="resources/template/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="resources/template/css/color-picker/minicolors.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link href="resources/template/fonts/icomoon/icomoon.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link href="resources/template/css/wysiwyg-editor/editor.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link href="resources/template/css/datatables/fixedHeader.bs.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link href="resources/template/css/datatables/dataTables.bs.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="resources/template/css/datatables/autoFill.bs.min.css">
<%@include file="static/header.jsp"%>
</head>

<body>
    <%@include file="static/top-header.jsp"%>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
        <%@include file="static/nav.jsp"%>
        <div class="dashboard-wrapper">
            <div class="top-bar clearfix">
                <div class="row gutter">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="page-title">
                            <h4>Gestion des Equipes</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-container">
                <div class="row gutter">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-blue">

                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4>Liste des Equipes</h4>
                            </div>

                            <div id="menuBarDiv" style="margin-left: 500px;">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="icon-printer2"></i> Imprimer
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="openAddModalBtn">
                                    <i class="icon-users3"></i> Nouvelle Equipe
                                </button>
                            </div>

                            <div class="bar bar-header"></div>
                            <div class="panel-body">

                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="tableTeams"
                                        class="table table-striped table-bordered no-margin">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th class="text-center">Nom</th>
                                                <th class="text-center">Validateur</th>
                                                <th class="text-center">Couleur</th>
                                                <th class="text-center">Statut</th>
                                                <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <c:forEach var="t" items="${teams}">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="text-center">${t.name }</td>
                                                    <td class="text-center">${t.validateur.firstName}
                                                        ${t.validateur.lastName}</td>
                                                    <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-square"
                                                        aria-hidden="true"
                                                        style="background-color:<c:out value="${t.color}"></c:out>; width= "></i></td>
                                                    <td class="text-center"><c:choose>
                                                            <c:when test="${t.isActif == true }">
                                                                <i class="icon-lens" style="color: #077a07;"></i>
                                                            </c:when>
                                                            <c:when test="${t.isActif == false }">
                                                                <i class="icon-lens" style="color: #c20b0b;"></i>
                                                            </c:when>
                                                        </c:choose></td>
                                                    <td class="text-center"><a
                                                        href="#update-team-modal_${t.id}" role="button"
                                                        class="btn btn-xs btn-transparent btn-info"
                                                        data-toggle="modal"><i
                                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-placement="bottom"
                                                            title="Editer"></i></a> <a
                                                        href="detailsTeam?id=<c:out value="${t.id}"></c:out>">
                                                            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-transparent btn-info">
                                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"
                                                                    data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
                                                                    title="Voir Détails"></i>
                                                            </button>
                                                    </a><a
                                                        href="desactivateTeam?id=<c:out value="${t.id}"></c:out>">
                                                            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-transparent btn-danger ">
                                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-off"
                                                                    data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
                                                                    title="Désactiver"></i>
                                                            </button>
                                                    </a></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <div class="modal fade" id="update-team-modal_${t.id}"
                                                    tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
                                                    aria-hidden="true">
                                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                                <h5>Modification Equipe</h5>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                                <form id="updateTeamForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                                                                    method="POST" action="updateTeam">

                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <input id="id" type="hidden" name="id"
                                                                            class="form-control" value="${t.id}">
                                                                    </div>

                                                                    <label for="name">Nom </label><span class="req">*
                                                                    </span>
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <div class="input-group">
                                                                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"
                                                                                class="form-control-large" value="${t.name }"
                                                                                required="required" />
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>

                                                                    <label for="color">Couleur</label><span class="req">*
                                                                    </span>
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <input type="text" id="color" name="color"
                                                                            class="form-control demo" style="width: 200px;"
                                                                            data-swatches="#fff|#000|#f00|#0f0|#00f|#ff0|#0ff"
                                                                            value="${t.color}" required="required">
                                                                    </div>

                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <label for="validateur">Validateur</label> <span
                                                                            class="req">* </span> <select
                                                                            class="form-control-small" id="validateur"
                                                                            name="validateur" required="required">
                                                                            <option value="${t.validateur.matricule}">${t.validateur.firstName }
                                                                                ${t.validateur.lastName }</option>
                                                                            <c:forEach var="u" items="${users}">
                                                                                <option value="${u.matricule}">${u.firstName}
                                                                                    ${u.lastName}</option>
                                                                            </c:forEach>
                                                                        </select>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </form>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                                <a><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-ok" data-dismiss="modal" id="update">
                                                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" ></i>Editer
                                                                    </button></a>
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                                                                    data-dismiss="modal">
                                                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>Annuler
                                                                </button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </c:forEach>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="add-team-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5>Nouvelle Equipe</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="addTeamForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"
                        action="addTeam">
                        <label for="name">Nom </label><span class="req">* </span>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name"
                                    class="form-control-large" required="required" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <label for="color">Couleur</label><span class="req">* </span>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="color" name="color"
                                class="form-control demo" style="width: 200px;"
                                data-swatches="#fff|#000|#f00|#0f0|#00f|#ff0|#0ff"
                                required="required">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="validateur">Validateur</label> <span class="req">*
                            </span> <select class="form-control-small" id="validateur"
                                name="validateur" required="required">
                                <option value="">-- Sélectionner un validateur --</option>
                                <c:forEach var="u" items="${users}">
                                    <option value="${u.matricule}">${u.firstName}
                                        ${u.lastName}</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a><button type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-info btn-ok">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>Créer
                        </button></a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="cancelAdd"
                        data-dismiss="modal">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>Annuler
                    </button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <%@include file="static/footer.jsp"%>
    <script src="resources/template/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/template/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/template/js/scrollup/jquery.scrollUp.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/template/js/sparkline/sparkline.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/template/js/sparkline/custom-sparkline.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/template/js/databars/jquery.databar.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/template/js/databars/custom-databars.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/template/js/datatables/dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="resources/template/js/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/template/js/datatables/autoFill.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="resources/template/js/datatables/autoFill.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/template/js/datatables/fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/template/js/datatables/custom-datatables.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/template/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/template/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/template/js/fileinput/fr.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/template/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/template/js/color_picker/jscolor.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/template/js/color-picker/minicolors.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/template/js/color-picker/custom-colorpicker.js"></script>

    <script>
        $("#filtre").on("change", function() {
            var selected = this.value;
        });

        $('#openAddModalBtn').on('click', function() {
            $('#add-team-modal').modal('toggle');

        });

        $('#cancelAdd').on('click', function() {
            $('#add-team-modal').find("input").val('').end();
            document.getElementById('validateur').selectedIndex = 0;
        });

        $('#save').on('click', function() {

            $('#addTeamForm').ajaxForm({
                success : function(data) {
                    var res = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (res.code == 1) {
                        $('#add-team-modal').modal('hide');
                        location.reload();
                        $('#add-team-modal').find("input").val('').end();
                    }

                    else {
                        toastr["error"](res.message);
                    }
                },
                error : function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }).submit();
        });

        $('#update').on('click', function() {

            $('#updateTeamForm').ajaxForm({
                success : function(data) {
                    var res = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (res.code == 1) {
                        $('#add-team-modal').modal('hide');
                        location.reload();
                    }

                    else {
                        toastr["error"](res.message);
                    }
                },
                error : function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }).submit();
        });
        $('#tableTeams').DataTable({
            "language" : {
                "url" : "resources/template/lang/French.json"
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```